# Prove existence of infimum/supremum of bounded set

Tags: real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

How can one prove existance of infimum/supremum of bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$? More precisely, how can one prove that if there exists a lower bound of a set, there also exists maximum lower bound?

Comment: How do you define "$\mathbb R$"? There are several possibilities, and the differences between them **are wildly important** for proving properties as basic as this.

Comment: It wouldn't be true with the definitions I normally use, but as Henning says, with your definition (that we don't know) of $\mathbb R$ it might be.

Comment: (Henrik's point is that you have forgotten to specify that the subset be non-empty).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: If that is what Henrik tries to say, then indeed thank you for having translated that to us. Hegel couldn't have said it in a more convoluted way.

Comment: Can anyone suggest some proof along with the definition of $mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @procurator: There's no "the" definition of $\mathbb R$. _You_ need to tell _us_ **which definition you use** before you can reasonably hope to get a proof that works with the particular $\mathbb R$ you're talking about.

Comment: The property of real numbers you seem to have in mind (bounded nonempty subsets have a unique supremum, resp. infimum) depends on the *order* and *completeness* of the real numbers.  Familiarity with those properties would be required, I think, to ask your Question.